# My link button is not shown selected (lacking border)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-5

I have a link button as shown in the code below:

```
<div class="col-2">
      <a type="button" routerLink="auto-generate-schedules/generate" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Generate Schedules
      </a>
            </div>
```

... which when I click on it, it does not display any border indicating it is selected. But the few bootstrap buttons below it, display that border. What do I need to do to have border around my link button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="col-2">
  <a type="button" routerLink="auto-generate-schedules/generate" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Generate Schedules
  </a>
        </div>    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
```

Comment: It's an anchor link, those redirect to somewhere else. It doesn't really make any sense to have them as selected, because the moment you click them you aren't looking at the link anymore. You are trying to redirect somewhere yes? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. But when I get back to the view with those `buttons` (from somewhere else) I would like to display which button triggered last action (so I would like to show the selection border to the user - is this possible)

Comment: Yeah, in that case the solution by @Naren Murali should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are using `a` tag few bootstrap styles are missed, the solution will be to wrap a button with the styles you want inside a `a` tag which has the `routerLink` set which will give the behaviour you want!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-2">
  <a routerLink="auto-generate-schedules/generate"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Generate Schedules
  </button></a>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
```

Comment: I admit it works in an example now but somehow it does not work inside my app. Not sure what is wrong with it. Even if I remove all ` routerLink=""` from all `a` elements (so it does go anywhere) it still does not show outlined border?

Comment: @janci try doing an inspect element on the button and  and check what styles on the right side of the elements tab are getting overridden, that will help you resolve it

Comment: what exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: @janci actually in the button there is no border color is your complaint, check the CSS property `color` and `border-color` see where its getting changed using inspect element!

Comment: I have prepared stackBlitz of my app that illustrates the problem I am having with the real app [example](https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/rejkid/angular-router-test). No matter which button you click none of them is shown as selected (with the border color changed). Should I raise that as a new issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the way you import Bootstrap libraly.
You should add this to your index.html (the file is in public folder)

```
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The result
[image: result]

Comment: Why do I need to import bootstrap from index.html. Documentation says this https://www.laratutorials.com/install-bootstrap-5-in-angular-16/

Comment: Use npm like the documentaion to install bootstrap is a good way. But using CND is the easiest way.   
I think the probem might be that you missed some steps or classes...

Comment: If this help can you accpet my answer. This will help me a a lot!

Comment: To me the answer is a combination of your answer and Naren Murali - how can I reward two of you?

Comment: A up vote is ok. I tried to get enough 50 reputation. Now I done! Thank you.